# Optimal way to calculate cosine similarity between a target string to list of strings - Python

Tags: scikit-learn

I have a target string, say `target = 'apple'` and I have a list of candidate strings, say `candidate_list = ['orange', 'banana', 'apple1', 'pineapple']`. I am calculating cosine similarity between `target` and iterating over each string in `candidate_list` using the following code.

```
def calculate_cosine(c, h):
   vec = CountVectorizer()
   label_dictionary = vec.fit([c, h])
   c_vector = label_dictionary.transform([c]).toarray()
   h_vector = label_dictionary.transform([h]).toarray()

   cx = lambda curr, hist: round(
      numpy.inner(curr, hist) / numpy.LA.norm(curr) * numpy.LA.norm(hist), 3)

   return cx(c_vector, h_vector)
```

My question is, is there a way to do this without iterating over the `candidate_list` on the lines of [Array Broadcasting](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/user/basics.broadcasting.html) or like Matrix Operation. 
I am asking this since my current implementation (looping over the `candidate_list`) is not fast enough for my application.
Thanks.

Comment: One note: your cosine similarity computation is incorrect: you probably meant ``numpy.inner(curr, hist) / (numpy.LA.norm(curr) * numpy.LA.norm(hist))``

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Scikit-learn contains efficient code for computing the cosine similarity between groups of vectors; it's in the `sklearn.metrics.pairwise` submodule.

Here's a fast approach for your problem:

```
from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import CountVectorizer
from sklearn.metrics import pairwise_kernels

candidate_list = ['orange', 'banana', 'apple1', 'pineapple']
target = 'apple'

vec = CountVectorizer(analyzer='char')
vec.fit(candidate_list)

pairwise_kernels(vec.transform([target]),
                 vec.transform(candidate_list),
                 metric='cosine')
# array([[ 0.3086067 ,  0.30304576,  0.93541435,  0.9166985 ]])
```

Note that I used `CountVectorizer(analyzer='char')` to count characters rather than words, because it seemed more appropriate for your example data.